# Access jar from one eclipse plugin in another plugin

Tags: java, jar, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How can I access a jar file in plugin A while the jar is available in another plugin B.

I added plugin B as dependency to plugin A but it seems not working. Actually the plugin B is just a wrapper plugin which contains the jar file and I want this jar to be available in different plugins.

How can I achieve this in RCP application.

Edit

I added the jar under Runtime ->classpath in the manifest added all the packages under Runtime -> Exported Packages and in the plugin where I need it I added the wrapper plugin as dependency.

When I try to execute this code

```
 try {
        Class.forName( "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver" );
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/util/ErrorHandler
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MANIFEST.MF editor for the plugin containing the jar add the jar to the 'Classpath' on the 'Runtime' tab. You should then be able to export the packages in the jar in the 'Exported Packages' section.

These steps update the `Bundle-ClassPath` and `Export-Package` entries in the plugin MANIFEST.MF

Comment: What is `com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/util/ErrorHandler`? That is not the class you are loading.

Comment: actually there are 3 wrapper plugins everyone include a jar file, one is ucanaccess.jar, jackcess.jar and hsqldb.jar

Comment: They all need to have the class path and exported packages set. The plugin dependencies also need to be set for all plugins that use classes in other plugins. Eclipse will only ever look for classes in the plugin's dependencies, it will never look anywhere else.

Comment: All the three wrapper plugins have their corresponding jar files in classpath and all the packages of the jars are added under exported packages and in the plugin I added all 3 wrapper plugins as dependenies